# anchor url not not working after applying css transition

Tags: html, css, hover, anchor, transition

With the help of someone on Stackoverflow I created a transition effect for a website where the background image on the navigation links change as the cursor is hovered.  The problem I'm having is that now link to the url isn't working, or it's not working all the time.  Here's the jsbin http://jsbin.com/geyod/4/edit . FYI on my website I have 11 images that I'm using, but from what I understand that shouldn't make a difference.  I didn't want to add all 11 images if not needed. I'm trying to replicate what has been done on this website http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/css3-animation.html#x .

Comment: What browser are you using? I'm using chrome and when I hover over the link and right-click -> "Open link in new tab" it takes me to affordable.html all of the time. Is that not the intended behavior?

Comment: Keyvan Sadralodabai I'm using chrome.  It's supposed to be a link for the navigation on the website.  Just regular click and get to another page of the site. The intent is not to right click or control click.

Comment: Are you saying when you click on the image it goes to that page?  Not sure why it's not working for me. ARE you using chrome?

Comment: Actually I take that back. It only works for me when I right-click the link, then select "Open link in new tab" I just downloaded the HTML and CSS to my local HTML file and I see that it's not working. Give me a min to get you a response.

Answer (score 0):

I *just* tested this and it works. Is this waht you're trying to achieve?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>JS Bin</title>
  <style> 
ul
{
 list-style-type: none;
 }
a
{
float: left;
display: block;
}

a.a1 {
    width: 201px;
    height: 149px;
    background-image: url("http://placehold.it/201x149"); /* Any image you want for your first link */
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

}
a.a1:hover {
    background-image: url("http://placehold.it/200x150"); /* Any image you want for your first link on mouse over */
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
a.a2 {
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
    background-image: url("http://placehold.it/200x150"); /* Any image you want for your second link */
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

}
a.a2:hover {
    background-image: url("http://placehold.it/220x125"); /* Any image you want for your second link on mouse over */
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
a.a3 {
    width: 201px;
    height: 149px;
    background-image: url("http://placehold.it/201x149"); /* Any image you want for your third link */
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

}
a.a3:hover {
    background-image: url("http://placehold.it/200x150"); /* Any image you want for your first link on mouse over */
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
</style>
    </head>
    <body>
     <div class = "footer"> 

            <nav>

                <p class="footertext">Text Here</p>

                <div class="clear"></div>
                <ul>
                <li class="GetOnList hover"> 
                <a class="a1" href="afordable.html"></a>
                <a class="a2" href="afordable.html"></a>
                  <a class="a3" href="afordable.html"></a>
                </li>
                </ul>

            </nav>



        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following what you're doing.  The jsbin I have only has 3 images but the project I'm working this for is using 11 images that go through an animation when the cursor hovers and moves over the li.  It looks like what you did was just a background change on hover.  If you check this site out http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/css3-animation.html#x you'll see what I'm trying to do. If I misunderstood you I'll see if this makes a difference in my code.

Comment: With the above... you can have a hundred images and it'll work as long as you keep adding <a> tags to it.

Comment: The changes that I made include wrapping your <li> tags within a <ul> tag... having an <li> tag without an encompassing <ul> or <ol> is not valid.

Comment: Whoever had you doing all the relative positioning and messing around with z-index properties wasn't so clever.

Comment: I'm pretty new at this so it's going take me a minute to see how this compares to what I have.  I can't tell if it will involve more code than using the z-index transition I'm using, but after thinking about it it looks like it might work. I'll get this together tomorrow.

Comment: Take your time bud :)

Comment: I started messing around with it, it went faster than I thought but the link still doesn't seem to work when I click it.  If I refresh the page and start over I can click the link and it works the first time but when I go back to the page it doesn't seem to work anymore.  It's late here so I may be doing something wrong but the animation seems to be working just not the clicking part.

Comment: Do you want an animated background change to run continuously while hovering over a link? If so, the CSS z-index trickery is not going to work well for you. If a new element gets positioned under the cursor via a z-index change, it won't necessarily be treated as hovered-over unless the mouse moves a tiny bit. Your cssplay.co.uk example shows this. Similarly, if an anchor gets itself positioned under the cursor, rather than the user positioning the mouse over the anchor, I'm not surprised that the anchor is not "live". I would do the animation with jquery or css3, not z-index.

Comment: I want the animation to run just like it does in the example at cssplay.co.uk, so that only when the cursor is moved the animation plays.  Can you explain what you mean by the anchor getting positioned under the cursor? Nevermind, I see what you mean.  I tried using :active on the element and :active + a and it works at certain points in the z-index.  Without the :active class, the anchor never gets activated. What css3 options were you talking about?